# finding novelty of document

Tags: nlp, k-means, similarity, cosine-similarity

I have a collection of documents created at different times. I need to know for each new incoming document, how similar it is to the set of documents already added. New documents can add new terms, and hence in such documents I would expect "novelty" to be high. I need to get a sense of this novelty (or alternatively, distance)

For example, say there are d0, d1, d2 , d3 already and I have a new document d4

I want to get a sense of how different d4 is from d0, d1, d2 and d3.

I have thought of a few ways but there are  a few limitations:

a) comput cosine similarity between each of (d0, d4) , (d1, d4), (d2, d4) , (d3, d4)

- find the average cosine similarity.

OR

find the min of negative of cosine angle between the new document, d4,  and each previously seen document i.e. d0, d1, d2, d4

the idea being that the minimum will give a sense of the novelty  of d4.

b) combine d0, d1, d2, d3  and compare it to d4 
and then find cosine similarity

Do these approaches seem ok? Moreover, are there more suitable ways to get a sense of novelty, perhaps with K-means clustering?

Comment: Try to combine d0, d1, d2, d3 and use them as a regular class in OneClassSVM.

Answer (score 1):

Compute the Estimate for [Multionomial Distribution](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/multinomial-distributions-over-words-1.html) over the words in your collection, and a separate distribution for words in a new document. Compute the [KL-divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) to get a feeling how distant these distributions are.

Comment: these documents are relatively short, would KL divergence be suitable for this?

Comment: yes, as long as you have enough amount of your short text.

Answer (score 1):

What if d0, d1, d2 and d3 are dissimilar? And d4 is very similar to d0 and totally different from d3, since d0 and d3 are very different.

Combining d0-N will probably not be a good idea, since the bigger N the bigger chance that d(n+1) will be a subset of d(0-N).

In fact document level novelty detection is considered rarely useful, as nearly every document will have something new. To deal with the problem, instead of measuring the document novelty, you can measure the topic novelty using hPAM to retrieve the topics and cosine similarity for detecting the difference. You can also use novelty score proposed in [NOVELTY DETECTION VIA TOPIC MODELING IN RESEARCH ARTICLES by Sendhilkumar](http://airccj.org/CSCP/vol3/csit3542.pdf), which is shown to be better.

Comment: would this work for short documents, which is the setting I am working in. 
Also, these documents aren't radically dissimilar.

Comment: It shouldn't matter. Regarding the topic modeling, since hPAM is only implemented in Mallet, which is kind of awkward unless working with Java, you can try LDA to observe the initial metrics.